# Why MySQL replication fails to resume correctly after master server is re-booted?

Tags: mysql, database-replication

I have a MySQL master-slave replication. Recently a server where mysql master is hosted - was rebooted due to some issues (not related with mysql).  After the server got up I was totally unaware of the fact that the synchronization with slaves was broken (master log file name changed). We updated the master database structure, plus a lot of data changed. After ~24 hours we realized that slaves dont have the new data structure and new data. Synchronization is broken.

I'm now trying to fix it, but I'm wondering - why can't just slave instance automatically pick up where it was left when the master server was stopped (to whatever reason)? Why is it implemented such way that slave instances totally lose track of what's happening when master server is restarted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The replica is supposed to recover, either if the replica or the master restarts.

The replica has a file in its data directory called `relay-log.info` that records the last event the replica processed. Most of the time, this works well, and a replica can resume where it left off.

However, a number of things can go wrong:

- The relay-log.info can become corrupted if the replica crashes. For this reason, in MySQL 5.6, they now offer the option to store the same information in a crash-safe InnoDB table instead of in a file.
- The replica can be offline for a long time. If the master purges the binary log file that the replica was reading from when it stopped, the replica can't continue. The replica needs to read a contiguous series of events, or else it can't assure full data replication.
- The master might corrupt its binary log files if the master crashes. You can reduce this risk by enabling the `sync-binlog` configuration variable on the master, with the understanding that it decreases performance on the master.

As for "why is it implemented [in] such [a] way," why don't you try implementing a replication system that can recover from crashes, and see how easy it is? :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on a Master-Master replication setup from the beginning on a clean system and clean VMs and it turned out that the permissions for the replication user account on each server allowing the other server to read the binlog index file on the master and vice versa were not allowing this so they got out of step and every time the binlog index number changed which on my system is every time the MySQL service restarts or the host server reboots, the replication broke in one way or the other depending on which server rebooted.

I took the lazy way out as I was only testing in a VM environment and just gave the replication user (on both servers) full permissions over everything and the issue was fixed but to be more correct, the better way to do this would be to make sure that the replication user has permissions as replication client AND replication slave on both servers.   If that doesn’t fix it, go through the permissions until you find the one that allows each server to read the binlog index on the other server.  This way they won’t get out of step, assuming this is the reason for your issues.

Check to see if the current active binlog matches what the other server is using to sync from the other server, and you may find that one server is looking for binlog.000006 and the other server is using a newer log like bin-log.000008 or something.

To che3ck the binlog on the slave or the master, type SHOW MASTER STATUS.  The result will show you the name and position in the log that the partner server needs to be looking at.  On the other server, run these commands...

STOP SLAVE;

CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST = 'ip_of_other_server', MASTER_USER = 'replication_user_name', MASTER_PASSWORD = 'replication_user_password', MASTER_LOG_FILE = 'mysql-bin.0000??', MASTER_LOG_POS = value_from_other_server;

START SLAVE;

NOTE: Don’t put quotes around the master log pos value.
The master log filename would be the one shown on the other server after running the SHOW MASTER STATUS on that server.   If you have a master-master setup, you need to apply these instructions to both servers but switch the IP to the address of the server your NOT running the instructions from in each case.   You can run these using MySQL workbench or MySQL command line from MySQL BIN folder.

Once you get the servers syncing again, if they keep disconnecting afterr eaither server is rebooted, then check permissions for the account used for the replication.